# Evaluating inline C# code from post content

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have been around in circles with this one and need some help. I have a method that evaluates code, so if I pass this `Eval("DateTime.Now.Year - 1986")` it returns 29, its working great and this means I can have inline code in my posts that dynamically evaluate at runtime (this might present some security concerns, but that for some other time), here's the example string I am trying to work with: `string inStr = "this year is [EVAL]DateTime.Now.Year[/EVAL] and it has been [EVAL]DateTime.Now.Year - 1986[/EVAL] years since 1986";` I need a regex that will replace all [EVAL] instances and return the full text with the evaluated results. Anyone?

Comment: You know that you could simply `IndexOf("[EVAL]")` without fighting against regexes?

Comment: @Zaki: I think they're asking not to _remove_ the "[EVAL]" tokens only, but also to _replace/evaluate_ the expressions inside those flags. EDIT: that is, they have the evaluation code, so they only need to _extract_ the expressions.

Comment: You might try `string.Split()` along `"[EVAL]"` and `"[/EVAL]"` boundaries, storing into a custom data structure which essentially wraps two lists.  One of literal strings, and one of evaluate-able strings.  Then evaluate them and re-build the resulting string from the lists.

Comment: As a side note, have you considered using a technology that's made for this purpose? For example, if you saved your posts as Razor pages, you could use `@DateTime.Now.Year` syntax.

Comment: `(\[(EVAL)\]){1}([\w\.\d\s\-]+)\[\/(EVAL){1}\]` gives me two matches for your example string.

Comment: Not using razor views but web forms and the post text is coming from a SQL database with those [EVAL] bits. I can string replace the [EVAL]s but what I need is to put back the already evaluated text by using the `Eval("string")` method on each [EVAL] found, then returning the full string/post already transformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a Regex, you can have a regex...

```
string inStr = "this year is [EVAL]DateTime.Now.Year[/EVAL] and it has been [EVAL]DateTime.Now.Year - 1986[/EVAL] years since 1986";

var rx = new Regex(@"(\[EVAL\])(.*?)(\[/EVAL])");

string outStr = rx.Replace(inStr, RegexReplacer);
```

with

```
public static string RegexReplacer(Match match)
{
    return Eval(match.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

or depending on the return type of `Eval`:

```
public static string RegexReplacer(Match match)
{
    object obj = Eval(match.Groups[2].Value);
    return obj != null ? obj.ToString() : string.Empty;
}
```

The capture group #2 is the `(.*?)`. Note the use of the lazy quantifier `.*?`, because otherwise the capture would be `[EVAL]DateTime.Now.Year[/EVAL] and it has been [EVAL]DateTime.Now.Year - 1986[/EVAL]`

Comment: This worked, still have to test with more complex [EVAL]s but how do I get the return in one line `return rx.Replace(inStr, RegexReplacer);` without the seperate RegexReplacer?

Comment: @NelsonPires The minimal is something like: `string outStr = rx.Replace(inStr, match => Eval(match.Groups[2].Value))`

Comment: Amazing, thanks, it works great, the possibilities for my system just opened up massively. Thanks again.